# Can we jump to attractive questions?

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice to be able to jump to questions that have a large number of votes, but aren’t very old (in terms of last activity, not in terms of date of original posting). We could use a name for such questions. I’m using the name “attractive questions”, but perhaps someone can think of a better name. Anyway, a metric something along the lines of number of votes divided by age is called for. Would this be too big of a feature to implement in the not too distant future?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That already exists, SE uses the ["hotness"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) of a question e.g. for the list of hot questions in the StackExchange dropdown menu in the top left corner.

If you're only interested in Mathematics questions you can create a tag set for mathematics on stackexchange.com, [I already created one now to demonstrate this](http://stackexchange.com/filters/24755/mathematics?sort=hot). Just follow this link, you'll see that there is the option to sort by hotness, which will show questions that had a large number of votes and/or views recently.

Comment: Totally cool. I've up-voted and accepted your excellent answer!